# Regular Expressions multiple line

Tags: regex

I need mark 2 first characters in every line `(NY,27,NC)`. How to do this?
`([A-Z]{2})` mark 2 characters in the first line

```
NY104670000 12/31/0112/28/0112/28/01

279700000 12/31/0112/28/0112/28/01

NY100600000 12/31/0112/29/0112/29/01

NC279280000 12/31/0112/29/0112/29/01

NC278600000 12/31/0112/30/0112/30/01
```

Comment: What language, tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include starting anchor and also you need to change `([A-Z]{2})` to something like `(\w{2})` so that it would match also the  digits. And also don't forget to enable multiline mode.

```
^(.{2})
```

or

```
^(\w{2})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oK7eW9/13)

`{2}` repetition quantifier which repeats the previous pattern exactly two times. You don't need to include capturing groups   just matching would be fine.

```
^\w{2}
```

Comment: I suggest losing the brackets - there is no need to group; group 1 is identical to the whole match, and therefore redundant

Comment: @Natan Which language are you running?

Answer (score 0):

```
^..
```

Try this.See demo.This will select only first two.

http://regex101.com/r/sA8iT4/7